# How to access outer most JSON object values as well as inner most JSON object values based on validating middle value in JavaScript back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have a JSON data as below where the values should be taken from inner and outer object based on validating middle value.

For example: if cat=4, then I should create an object as below

```
"material_id": xcs2,
"cat": 4;
"title": "1ctrlX ",
"description": "1The single-axis ",
"link": "1example.com"
```

I managed to extract all except how to find material_id? Below is my code

```js
let data = [{
  "Products": {
    "xcs2": {
      "de_DE": {
        "cat": "45",
        "title": "deutsch - Umrichter",
        "description": "Die Einzelachs-Umrichter .",
        "link": "example.com"
      },
      "en_US": {
        "cat": "4",
        "title": "1ctrlX ",
        "description": "1The single-axis ",
        "link": "1example.com"
      }
    },

    "XCD1": {
      "de_DE": {
        "cat": "435",
        "title": "ctrlX ",
        "description": "Die ",
        "link": "example.com"
      },
      "en_US": {
        "cat": "4",
        "title": "2ctrlX ",
        "description": "2The single-axis ",
        "link": "2example.com"
      }
    }

  }
}]

var jsonobj = null;

data.filter(item => { // here data is divided into multiple array and executes iterateobject fun on each item
  iterateObject(item)
})


function iterateObject(obj) {
  for (prop in obj) { // prop is the key here (should have de_DE and object)

    if (typeof(obj[prop]) == "object") { //  obj[prop] is the  value.
      iterateObject(obj[prop])
    } else {
      if (prop == "cat" && obj[prop] == 4) { // prop is the key  (imagining id 04)
        //console.log('category id :' + obj.cat.toUpperCase())
        category_id = obj.cat
        title = obj.title
        description = obj.description
        link = obj.link

        jsonobj = {
          "category_id": category_id,
          "title": title,
          "description": description,
          "link": link
        }
        
        console.log(jsonobj)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what parameters you want to use? Only `cat`? what about the `data` array, will it contain only one object or it can contain multiple objects?

Comment: yes, basically input parameters are cat and language code(if possible), ideally when the user clicks on category in angular only cat id is sent to backend.along with language code ! i have to send a json object back by validating cat and language code . Many thanks in advance

Comment: data contains only one object, called products and products contains multiple objects with no standard name which is cat.!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your latest comment I'm not sure that you need a recursive approach for this, but I've left it like that. In the following code the idea is to pass all the parent keys through to the child call of iterateObject so that you have them available when building the result object.

```js
let data = [{"Products":{"xcs2":{"de_DE":{"cat":"45","title":"deutsch - Umrichter","description":"Die Einzelachs-Umrichter .","link":"example.com"},"en_US":{"cat":"4","title":"1ctrlX ","description":"1The single-axis ","link":"1example.com"}},"XCD1":{"de_DE":{"cat":"435","title":"ctrlX ","description":"Die ","link":"example.com"},"en_US":{"cat":"4","title":"2ctrlX ","description":"2The single-axis ","link":"2example.com"}}}}];

const get_found_object = ({ cat: category_id, title, description, link }, material_id) => ({
  material_id, category_id, title, description, link
});

function iterateObject(obj, parent_keys = []) {
  let result = null;
  
  for (prop in obj) { // prop is the key here (should have de_DE and object)
    if (typeof(obj[prop]) == "object") { //  obj[prop] is the  value.
      result = iterateObject(obj[prop], [prop, ...parent_keys]);
      if(result) return result;
    } else if (prop == "cat" && obj[prop] == 4) {
      return get_found_object(obj, parent_keys[1]);
    }
  }
  
  return null;
}

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => acc || iterateObject(item), null);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i'm very new to development and kind of banging my head to do this.! i actually wrapped the Products JSON object into an array what if there is no array .! what changes should i make .!  here is the actual JSON -- >  https://www.codepile.net/pile/ELrrJzL4

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach if you need flexibilty with categoryId and language_code.

```js
let data = [
    {
        Products: {
            xcs2: {
                de_DE: {
                    cat: '45',
                    title: 'deutsch - Umrichter',
                    description: 'Die Einzelachs-Umrichter .',
                    link: 'example.com',
                },
                en_US: {
                    cat: '4',
                    title: '1ctrlX ',
                    description: '1The single-axis ',
                    link: '1example.com',
                },
            },

            XCD1: {
                de_DE: {
                    cat: '435',
                    title: 'ctrlX ',
                    description: 'Die ',
                    link: 'example.com',
                },
                en_US: {
                    cat: '4',
                    title: '2ctrlX ',
                    description: '2The single-axis ',
                    link: '2example.com',
                },
            },
        },
    },
];

function processInput(catId, lang_code = null) {
    const Products = data[0]['Products'];
    const result = Object.keys(Products)
        .map((material_id) =>
            Object.keys(Products[material_id])
                .filter((lang) =>
                    Products[material_id][lang]['cat'] == catId
                        ? lang_code === null
                            ? true
                            : lang === lang_code
                        : false
                )
                .map((filteredLang) => ({
                    material_id,
                    ...Products[material_id][filteredLang],
                }))
        )
        .flat();
    return result;
}
console.log(processInput(4));
console.log(processInput(435));
console.log(processInput(435, 'en_US'));
console.log(processInput(435, 'de_DE'));
```

Comment: As i said i'm new to javascript and didn't understand your code as i'm still working on my javascript basics and please recommend any youtube channel if you know for me to better understand  ...Products notation and .map . Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of recommeding a youtube video, i will suggest you to go through this [freecodecamp Javascript curriculum](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/). Here, you will have Hands-0n experience with this you will be learning in the process.

Comment: Thanks Dipanshu, i found one course in learning.oreilly.com by brad traversy, once i complete it i will take a look at your suggested course